# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener adding spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got the error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

when deploying only if I include the following piece of code between "Spring Security" and "END Spring Security" in the file `web.xml`. If I remove this part of the code in the XML everything works fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        version="2.5">


 <!-- Spring MVC -->
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>floorOperationWS</servlet-name>
 <servlet- class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>floorOperationWS</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/floorOperationWS/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>updatefloorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.services.endpoint.UpdatefloorEventServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>updatefloorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/updatefloorWS</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

     <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <!-- END Spring Security -->

</web-app>
```

-- spring-security.xml :

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

-- MAVEN dependencies:

```
            <properties>        
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <!--  org.springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-v version-->
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- DB connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

What's causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Common problem causing this error is wrongly included spring jar
You didnt mention your ide so i assume you are using eclipse
Solution for this is

1.Double click on server used for deploying

2.Click open Launch configuration - classpath tab

3.Click Add External Jars

4.add spring jar

5.run your application

Comment: Hi, i am using eclipse and the classpath seems to be OK:                   M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Ok you can try one more thing Open the project's properties
Then go to deployment assembly ther you have to click Add..
Select Java Build Path Entries from Directive Type menu and click Next.
Select Maven Dependencies from Java Build Path Entries and click finish

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project with given details two issue I faced :
> Spring security version : 3.2.3.RELEASE
change it to 3.1.6.RELEASE //(although this case should not give an error )
> in given pom you have not added spring-mvc jar
after adding this it works for me

Comment: I've tried with 3.1.6 with the same result, spring-mvc was included as well: <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
 <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
</param-value>
```

for in applicationContext.xml

```
<import resource="spring-security.xml" />
```

solved the problem